# Not able to access two different action under two different controllers in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two controllers which contain different action name, I am trying to access them, I am able to access PrepareTransmittalLetterPath under Transmittal controller but not able to access PrepareConcreteReport under Concrete controller.

May be my web api route is not working properly. Thanks in advance.

Transmittal Controller--where TransmittalApi is a class

```
public string PrepareTransmittalLetterPath(TransmittalApi transmittalApi)
{

}
```

Concrete Controller- where ConcreteReportApi is a class

```
public ConcreteReportApi PrepareConcreteReport(ConcreteReportApi concreteApi)
{

}
```

WebApiConfig-

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the endpoint (url) you are trying ? also do you have other action methods in the controller which is responding to your call  ? what response are you getting

Comment: I am trying to access the concrete controller using 'response = confClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Concrete/PrepareConcreteReport/0", concreteApi).Result;' and I am getting error 404, No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI http://localhost:45874/api/Concrete/PrepareConcreteReport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using convention-based routes means your action method names need to start with `Get....` or `Post....`.

> To find the action, Web API looks at the HTTP method, and then looks for an action whose name begins with that HTTP method name. For example, with a GET request, Web API looks for an action that starts with "Get...", such as "GetContact" or "GetAllContacts". This convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods. You can enable other HTTP methods by using attributes on your controller.

See [Routing in Asp.Net Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) for more information.